# Fill blank space with value in SQL Serve r2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using a SQL query in SQL Server 2012.

I have a table with the following data:

```
       ID headervalue  details
       -----------------------------
        1  zero         testzero
        2               testzero1
        3  Test         testtest1
        4  First        testfirst1
        5               testfirst2
        6               testfirst3
        7               testfirst4
        8 Second        testSecond1
```

I need the output as the following:

```
       ID headervalue details
        1  zero       testzero
        2  zero       testzero1
        3  Test       testtest1
        4  First      testfirst1 
        5  First      testfirst2
        6  First      testfirst3
        7  First      testfirst4 
        8 Second      testSecond1
```

How can I replace the blank space with the existing values?

Can anybody help?

Comment: Why does `testzero` become `testzero1` and `testzero1` become `testzero2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CROSS APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx):

Test data:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(ID int, headervalue varchar(10),   details varchar(30))
INSERT @t VALUES
(1, 'zero', 'testzero'),
(2, '', 'testzero1'),
(3, 'Test', 'testtest1'),
(4, 'First', 'testfirst1'),
(5, '', 'testfirst2'),
(6, '', 'testfirst3'),
(7, '', 'testfirst4'),
(8, 'Second', 'testSecond1')
```

Query:

```
SELECT t.id, x.headervalue, t.details 
FROM @t t
CROSS APPLY
  (
     SELECT top 1
       headervalue
     FROM @t
     WHERE
       headervalue <> '' 
       and id <= t.id
     ORDER BY id DESC) x
```

Result:

```
id  headervalue  details
1   zero         testzero   
2   zero         testzero1  
3   Test         testtest1  
4   First        testfirst1 
5   First        testfirst2 
6   First        testfirst3 
7   First        testfirst4 
8   Second       testSecond1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using window functions:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(headervalue) OVER (PARTITION BY grp), details
FROM (
SELECT ID, headervalue, details,
       SUM(CASE WHEN headervalue <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS grp
FROM mytable ) AS t
```

The sub-query used above, i.e.

```
SELECT ID, headervalue, details,
       SUM(CASE WHEN headervalue <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS grp
FROM mytable
```

yields the following output:

```
ID  headervalue details     grp
--------------------------------
1   zero        testzero    1
2               testzero1   1
3   Test        testtest1   2
4   First       testfirst1  3
5               testfirst2  3
6               testfirst3  3
7               testfirst4  3
8   Second      testSecond1 4
```

Hence, `grp` helps us identify groups of 'to-be-named-the-same' `headervalue` records. Applying `MAX` over those slices of records gives us the expected result for `headervalue` per `grp` slice.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d5d7f/1)